# Pandas - Convert object to string and then to int

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following data frame.

[image]

What I am trying to do is

1. Convert this object to a string and then to a numeric

I have looked at using the astype function (string) and then again to int. What I would like to get is the data type to be

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(string).astype(int).
```

I have tried other variations. What I have been trying to do is get the column values to become a number(obviously without the columns). It is just that the data type is an object initially.
[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: If the datatype is "object" that means it's probably a string already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all the `,`:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

With both columns, you can do:

```
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].replace(',', '', regex=True).astype('int')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So much cleaner too. Also, curious how would you create a lambda function out of this?

Comment: `func = lambda x: x.str.replace(',','').astype(int); df.apply(func)`. But also try my second approach

Comment: Don't you have to specify the column specifically when calling the apply function. df['a'].apply(func)?

Comment: No, that lambda takes in a series. There is a different between `apply` on frame and on series.